# How do you create PDF Form Fields that will expand to contain their content?

Tags: pdf, acrobat, livecycle

I have a field on a PDF form that could be too small for the contents it needs to hold.  Since it is already nearly the size of the page, I need a way to tell adobe to let that field grow to cover more than a page.

I haven't found any way to do this.  LiveCycle seems to act like you can do it, but everything tried so far, does not do anything more than add a scroll bar in the online view, and the fails to print all the content.  Acrobat doesn't even act like it is possible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you select the field, go to the Layout Palette (Palettes Menu -> Layout (Shift + F9) ) and select the "Expand to Fit" box next to the width and/or height it will expand when more text is entered.