# Dynamic - Expanding Text Box in Adobe Acrobat X Pro?

Tags: pdf, adobe, acrobat, livecycle

I have some forms that I need to add expanding text boxes to.
I already have Multi-Line selected.  And yes the scroll-bar appears when field is full and you keep entering text.  However, when you go to print, it doesn't print out the full text.

I know in Adobe LiveCycle you can make dynamic forms, that bump onto the next page.  I have done this, but you lose so much functionality in LiveCycle.  To be dynamic you lose the ability to position objects without using tables and therefore doing designs and graphics are not as easy.

Has anyone found a way to do this in Adobe Acrobat X Pro?

At this point, I think it would be easier just to convince people that a web form is much easier to update and style any way you want with print CSS stylesheet.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3427573/how-do-you-create-pdf-form-fields-that-will-expand-to-contain-their-content#comment15904177_3427573

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To be dynamic you lose the ability to position objects without using tables and therefore doing designs and graphics are not as easy.

That is not true. A form being dynamic or not has nothing to do with having flowed or positioned content. A static form renders once on the server, a dynamic form can be re-rendered on the client and thus is able to reflect layout changes like hiding objects or altering heights of objects ([more info](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/8.2/static_dynamic_diffs.pdf)).

With either form type you can have both positioned and flowed content. The trick is to divide your form into subforms according to the structure of the data you want to display ([tutorial](http://livedocs.adobe.com/livecycle/8.2/wb_designer/000103.html#1581109)).

To let the text field grow automatically with the amount of text, enclose it in a subform with flowed content, allow multiple lines and enable "expand to fit" (or "auto-fit).

Comment: Thanks, I gave it another go with the subforms divided for each content, based on flowed or positioned.  Don't know what I messed up earlier, but this time it work!  Thank you for the great answer with tutorial links, appreciate it. Next week I am going to start converting some of our forms from Acrobat Pro to LiveCycle.